# ASP.NET : Error 500 instead of Detailed Error

Tags: asp.net, web-config

All of a sudden i am getting a error 500 on my Asp.Net web application hosted on smarterasp.

I can access the pages but cant access any of the resources (CSS,JS,Images etc)
Here is a [CSS File](http://hscdesk.com/assets/plugins/blockUI/jquery.blockUI.js).

> The Error : The page cannot be displayed because an internal server
>   error has occurred.

Even if you try accessing a resource that does not exist, it should through a 404 but instead, you will get a 500. I tried contacting the support and they said everything is fine on their end.

I already have set customErrors=off.

```
<system.web>
  <trace enabled="false" />
  <customErrors mode="Off">
  </customErrors>
  <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: With custom errors mode off you can probably get a more detailed exception such as the server's stack trace when it encountered the error. If I can make an educated guess I'd say the permissions for the webserver to access your ressources have changed either on the disk or in some web.config, the root one or the ones located in the resource folders themselves.

Comment: Is it possible for you to test your ASP.NET web application in a local development environment? I have found that I get much more detailed error reports from my browser when viewing my web applications on localhost, as opposed to a remote web server.

Comment: Check again your web.config file, probably you've uploaded an invalid one.

Comment: Agreed, there's probably a web.config issue above that's causing the server to error before it parses the errors section of the config file

Comment: I removed the old web.config and uploaded new one after building, still same issue. The application runs fine on localhost.

Comment: Have you implemented any error logging system? like elmah ?

Answer (score 0):

I had defined **mimeMap** for static contents which was working fine before in web.config but then found out **StaticFileModule** was already installed on the web server which was causing the problem. 
(Probably they recently installed it)